# FIx or avoid using a FOR loop in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run the following operations in postgresql:

```
FOR realm_id IN (SELECT id from decision_realms WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT realm_id FROM voters WHERE realm_id IS NOT NULL)) 
LOOP
    INSERT INTO voters (voter_user_id, max_weight, actual_weight)
    SELECT contributor_user_id, pps, pps 
    FROM contributors WHERE 
        project_id= (SELECT project_id FROM goals WHERE id=(SELECT goal_id FROM decision_realms WHERE id=realm_id))
END LOOP;
```

They all work indepedently, this is:

```
 (SELECT id from decision_realms WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT realm_id FROM voters WHERE realm_id IS NOT NULL))
```

returns a single column of ids, and

```
INSERT INTO voters (voter_user_id, max_weight, actual_weight)
SELECT contributor_user_id, pps, pps 
FROM contributors WHERE 
    project_id= (SELECT project_id FROM goals WHERE id=(SELECT goal_id FROM decision_realms WHERE id=1))
```

fills the voters table with the rows as expected when realm_id is hardcoded to a value (1).

But if I try to replace the value 1, with a variable and loop on it based on the result of a select, the for loop does not works. It says there is a syntax error.

Can this be done without using a FOR LOOP? or how should I write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not elegant and not tested (it may have errors) but should be like that

```
INSERT INTO voters (voter_user_id, max_weight, actual_weight)
SELECT contributor_user_id, pps, pps
from
(
    SELECT contributor_user_id, pps, pps 
    FROM contributors WHERE 
        project_id in (
            (SELECT project_id FROM goals WHERE id in (SELECT goal_id FROM decision_realms 
                WHERE id in (SELECT id from decision_realms WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT realm_id FROM voters WHERE realm_id IS NOT NULL)) 
                ))
)dec_realms
```

Or using `with` statement

```
with dec_realms as
(
        SELECT contributor_user_id, pps, pps 
        FROM contributors WHERE 
            project_id in (
                SELECT project_id FROM goals WHERE id in (SELECT goal_id FROM decision_realms 
                    WHERE id in (SELECT id from decision_realms WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT realm_id FROM voters WHERE realm_id IS NOT NULL)) 
                    ))
)

INSERT INTO voters (voter_user_id, max_weight, actual_weight)
    SELECT contributor_user_id, pps, pps
    from dec_realms;
```

Other option is to use control structure `FOR` like that

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    _id integer;
BEGIN
    FOR _id IN (SELECT id from decision_realms WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT realm_id FROM voters WHERE realm_id IS NOT NULL)) 
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO voters (voter_user_id, max_weight, actual_weight)
        SELECT contributor_user_id, pps, pps 
        FROM contributors WHERE 
            project_id= (SELECT project_id FROM goals WHERE id=(SELECT goal_id FROM decision_realms WHERE id=_id));
    END LOOP;
END
$$
```

Im sory if i made errors, i do lack table structures. First and second option will be probably faster becouse 1 operation instead of executing each insert separately.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the syntax error, but I guess that the problem is that you have PL/pgSQL variables with the same name as columns that you use in queries.

Specifically, the loop variable is `realm_id`, which is also the name of a column in table `voters`.

The solution is to use different names for the variables.

Comment: thanks @Laurenz, that makes sense. Unfortunately, I changed but keep having the same error.

Comment: I have updated the script to 

DO
$$
DECLARE rid BIGINT;
BEGIN
 ALTER TABLE voters ALTER COLUMN id DROP NOT NULL;

 FOR rid IN 
  SELECT id from decision_realms WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT realm_id FROM voters WHERE realm_id IS NOT NULL) 
 LOOP
  INSERT INTO voters (voter_user_id, max_weight, actual_weight)
  SELECT contributor_user_id, pps, pps 
  FROM contributors WHERE 
   project_id= (SELECT project_id FROM goals WHERE id=(SELECT goal_id FROM decision_realms WHERE id=rid));
 END LOOP;

END
$$

and now it works... it seems I am confusing SQL statements with PSQL scripts...

Comment: see my proposed answer. I still dont know why it worked. I have a big migration .pgs file and so far I have not used DO $$ nor BEGIN

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked. Its probably that it must be a script and not only a statement... or something like that.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE rid BIGINT;
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE voters ALTER COLUMN id DROP NOT NULL;

    FOR rid IN 
        SELECT id from decision_realms WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT realm_id FROM voters WHERE realm_id IS NOT NULL) 
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO voters (voter_user_id, max_weight, actual_weight)
        SELECT contributor_user_id, pps, pps 
        FROM contributors WHERE 
        project_id= (SELECT project_id FROM goals WHERE id=(SELECT goal_id FROM decision_realms WHERE id=rid));
    END LOOP;

END
$$
```